# Spring Suite - @RequestMapping("/"), @GetMapping("/home") in controller file, leading to 404 error however, localhost:8080 o/p of index.html

Tags: spring, controller

The structure of the program is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwJAv.png)

**My employee file is **

```
package model;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Employee {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

}
```

**My controller file is:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HomeController {
    
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String getHome() {
        return "index";
    }
    

}
```

---

I have one html file in the static folder, which is getting executed with localhost:8080 command, but localhost:8080/welcome/home gives 404 not found error.

I was expecting localhost:8080/welcome/home to give o/p of index.html, or simply return "index" on the browser.

The Application file is executing properly without any error.

P.S. I am an absolute beginner in spring and trying to merely implement a very program using controllers and

output on browser is a simple White label Error Page

---

Comment: What does your project structure look like including the resources folder, main class, and your controller class and their position in the package

Comment: @zawarudo: kindly check the image posted above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have a Spring Boot App, so in order to have all packages scanned there are two approaches

First. Define packages in your main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"model", "config", "controller", "service"})
public class JwtAuthenticationApplication {
```

Second. Move your classes into SUBPACKAGE of your main class, which will help Spring to automatically scan all your packages.
So if your main class is located in `com.codemyth`
That means that the rest of your packages should be:

`com.codemyth.model` NOT `model`

`com.codemyth.config` NOT `config`

`com.codemyth.controller` NOT `controller`

`com.codemyth.service`  NOT `service`

I would advise you to use second approach that follows a standard how your packages should be structured in the Spring Boot application. Based on how Eclipse behaves I think that you can just left click on the config package and drag and drop it to `com.codemyth` package which will refactor it from config to `com.codemyth.config` which is what you want.

The root problem here is that none of your classes are being scanned due to your current package management.

Comment: Thanks a lot _/\_. In addition to the structure, lombok config also had a problem. So, I corrected the structure as advised by @zawarudo and manually generated the Getters, Setters, constructors, toString and then it resolved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, Lombok would make sense if it would solve a problem but instead of generating everything with IDE you write annotation, but most of the time I tried to use it it was buggy, so I am personally against it. It does not save any time and it is not worth using at least in my opinion when someone is just starting to learn.